# How to get only in-stock configurable option values in Magento2?

Tags: configurable-product, configurable-product-options, magento2.0.17, category-page

I want to get only the configurable option values which are ONLY in-stock.
For instance, assume 'size' is the configurable option and it's options are XS,S,M.L,XL,XXL. Product 'test' has only S,M,L and XL products are available. XS is out of stock. But when I call the function 
`$product->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableOptions($product);` it returns all the available sizes including `XS`. But I want it to be excluded.

Can someone give an idea on achieving this in the easiest manner `without loading the associated products and looping through them`? (because I want this value in the category page)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
I'm using Magento EE 2.0.17

Thanks.

Comment: where do you want to list all these products, i.e do you want on product page or want to implement in some custom module ?

Comment: hi @sukeshini how did you manage this. I have some similor requirement https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/348176/how-to-get-the-attribute-options-on-category-page-header-as-list-in-magento-2

Answer (score 0):

You should check this method of stock Registry **Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\StockRegistry $stockRegistry**:

```
public function getChildInStock($product)
{
    $inStock = [];
    foreach ($this->getAllowProducts($product) as $_product) {
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($_product->getId(), 1);
        $saleable = $stockItem->getIsInStock() && $this->verifyStock($stockItem);
        if($saleable){
            $inStock[] = $_product;
        }
    }
    return $inStock;
}
```

So you should pass configurable product and pass that product to

This will fetch all products which are intock